# Google Cloud Storage: Grant User / Pass credentials per object

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a web application whose backend is deployed to Google Cloud Functions, and it uses Google Cloud Storage to store documents of end users.
Users are authenticated to my application with Username and Password.

Is it possible to grant a specific read access to object on GCS for the object owner users, so that if User A owns document A on GCS, he's the only one to have access to it?

Thanks

Comment: Nope. I need per-object restrictions but ACLs (AFAIK) control access by Google account, not application-defined User & Password

Comment: I don't think there is a mechanism for that. What you can do is remove access to all users and for each user generate SA. To each SA assign one GCS (this SA is the only account being able to access). For new users generate SA in the registration process

Comment: This sounds a bit too complicated. I was thinking remove access to all users except a single SA and then use a Cloud Function as an authentication service in front of the bucket.
Can it work?

Comment: Cloud Functions would also work. My approach seems like a lot of work, but that's just a few api calls and should be much easier to maintain that a Cloud Function working as a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

[Cloud IAM Conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview) might be exactly what you are looking for.

> With Cloud IAM Conditions, you can choose to grant resource access to identities (members) only if configured conditions are met. For example, this could be done to configure temporary access for users in the event of a production issue or to limit access to resources only for employees making requests from your corporate office.

So for each member you can configure something like this:

```
"condition": {
    "title": Limit access to [Dedicated VM]
    "expression": "resource.type == "compute.googleapis.com/Instance" && resource.name == [Dedicated VM]"
}
```

There is a limit 20 rules per person, which shouldn't matter too much in this case.

Comment: Can IAM work also for users without a Google account? I mean that they only registered to my web app with User/Pass.

Comment: As far as I know - no. If this is the case you’d better create service account for each user

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can only control access to buckets with either Identity and Access Management (IAM) or Access Control Lists, as you can see on the [access control documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control), you can also get more details on each one at the related documentations.

What you are trying to do is not possible because either one of the options mentioned are dependent on having an google email and/or a google group email or something similar to assign the roles.

A possible workaround is what @lukaszberwid mentioned on the comments, if you have a bucket for each user their access will be independently managed, so it will probably suit your app's needs.

Hope this helps.